# windows api - detect when file of certain type is opened

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

Is it possible to have certain code executed whenever a file of a certain type is opened? In my case, I want to "listen" for when video files (".avi, mp4, etc.") are opened (either via the windows file explorer shell, or maybe directly from a video player?), so that I can store a history of played videos.

An hour's worth of googling turned up nothing, so I turn to you stackoverflow. Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: And If I open video file in hex editor, you are also add to the history of PLAYED videos???

Comment: @user2120666 Yes, that would be acceptable for my use case.

Comment: So hook CreateFile and/or ShellExecute.

Comment: Thanks @user2120666. I think I'll try to implement IShellExecuteHook

Comment: Hooking `ShellExecute` will only catch those instances where the user opens the file from `Explorer`.  If the user is already in a media player and does a File/Open on the file, it will most likely not see it.  Hooking `CreateFile` will catch them all (albeit a whole lot of other files too, so it will be much higher overhead).

Answer (score 5):

The best (and only reasonable way) to capture file system events (open/read/write) from arbitrary processes is by writing a [File System MiniFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you're developing a commercial product, please refrain from "hooking" Usermode APIs like CreateFile.  Doing so requires numerous, platform-specific hacks, and is a compatibility nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't hook `CreateFile` for this job. Windows has mechanisms built-in to handle jobs like this much more cleanly.

The easy way to handle this would be with [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465.aspx) with the `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS` flag. Any time a file is opened, its last-access time will be updated, so this tells you any time the file was opened.

Although it's pretty rare, that *can* "miss" changes under rare circumstances<sup>1</sup>. If you must have 100% accuracy (instead of, say, 99.9%), you can read [change journals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798.aspx) instead, but it's a fair amount of extra work for an advantage you may not care about.

---

<sup>1. There is one circumstance that isn't (necessarily) rare that you might care about though: `ReadDirectoryChangesW` will only work when/if your program is running. Change journals will let you know about things that happened even when your code isn't running at all.</sup>

Comment: This is not likely to work with modern (Post Windows XP) flavors of windows, as Last Access Timestamp updates are disabled by default for performance reasons.

Comment: I'll also add that NTFS change journals are obviously NTFS specific and won't help if the OP wishes to track such opens for files that reside on  non-NTFS volumes

Comment: If enabled, the last-access time stamp gets updated, when the respective file HANDLE is **closed**. You will not get notifications when the file is opened.